# unwanted dll being generated automatically

Tags: c++, windows, dll, openssl, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded our code (C++, on Win) from openssl 1 into openssl 3.
From some reason now there is a bcrypt.dll (which is a system dll) being generated automatically in our exe folder.

I don't understand how and why it's generated, and it causing problems because it suitable to the compiled machine and when running our program on another win version it crushes (because the prog uses it instead of the local win dll)

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How are you building your code?

Comment: in "Build", and it's mixed platforms projects (part are 32 and part are 64), so using build.cmd file

Comment: Without giving us more information and details about your problem - we can only provide you with wild guesses. Please improve your question so that we can properly address it. In your case what you should do is to provide us with the config file for the MS build project that you use to compile your program. This will most likely be a .vcxproj file. Along with that you should outline your project folder hierarchy so it is easier for us to navigate through the project config files. Edit: As it is a commercial project a minimal reproducible example would suffice.

Comment: the msi is built with *.vdproj, which I found out now is deprecated. 
could that cause the problem? should I attach it?

Comment: First thing is first: .vdproj is an MSI installer project IIRC. I believe it is not part of the actual build itself, but I might be mistaken. Secondly: I would always be careful when attaching anything that might be related to a commercial project. I think you should take time to make sure you are not releasing sensitive data. But once you make sure I would recommend attaching anything that will help us replicate this issue. My recommended approach would be to strip the proj files and replace the code with something we can run ourselves locally.